# Visio 2007 to Word 2000, images being changed during printing process

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, visio

I am currently sorting out some screenshots for some software documentation.  I take a screenshot, paste it into visio 2007, do some alterations and add shapes etc and then copy it into word 2000.

It all looks fine until I go to print.  On the printout each screenshot image from visio has the bottom 1/4 of the image cropped and put at the top.  I've tried copy paste and saving and inserting the file but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using "Paste Special" in Word and pasting it in as a Metafile or Enhanced Metafile? Or perhaps as a bitmap.

By default, Word will paste the Visio drawing in as an embedded OLE object, which you can double click to edit in Visio.

You lose that edit ability if you paste it as a different format, but it may give you different print results.